# laravel migration syntax error or access violation "Duplicate key name alter table and add index

Tags: php, laravel, migration, syntax-error

I am working on a new codebase giving to me which was writing in laravel

I tried to run migration but I am getting the error below

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1061 Duplicate key name 'artisan_services_user_id_index' (SQL: alter table `artisan_services` add index `artisan_services_user_id_i
ndex`(`user_id`))
```

This is the migration code.

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('artisan_services', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('user_id',10)->nullable();
            $table->text('profile_picture')->nullable();
            $table->longText('title')->nullable();
            $table->longText('full_name')->nullable();
            $table->text('feature_image')->nullable();
            $table->text('business_category')->nullable();
            $table->string('phone',50)->nullable();
            $table->longText('email')->nullable();
            $table->longText('website')->nullable();
            $table->text('cost')->nullable();
            $table->longText('per_service')->nullable();
            $table->longText('street_address')->nullable();
            $table->longText('city')->nullable();
            $table->longText('state')->nullable();
            $table->longText('service_description')->nullable();
            $table->longText('experience')->nullable();
            $table->string('status',10)->default(0)->nullable();
            $table->longText('rating')->nullable();
            $table->longText('review')->nullable();
            $table->longText('employers')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

        });
    }

   
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('artisan_services');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Saying that you've already somehow created that index. You need to drop that index before create. Put this code to top

```
 $table->dropIndex('artisan_services_user_id_index');
```